# How do you know when flash movie has finished playing in a flex container?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, loading

I have loaded an swf into a flex application.  It's been made a source of an  control.
I set the source of the image during the application's execution, upon setting the source, the movie plays, but I would like to know when it completes playing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a VideoDisplay component, you can use complete event or isPlaying check to see if the video's still running.

It it's a compiled swf loaded via SWFLoader, the swf can fire events, that can be captured by the parent flex app (this requires you have the source to the child swf , if you need to add events if they do not exist).

[How to raise an event from a SWF in a SWFLoader to a parent Flex application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195150/how-to-raise-an-event-from-a-swf-in-a-swfloader-to-a-parent-flex-application)