# flex4: fetch events from loaded swf using swfloader

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, swfloader, netconnection

I have a master swf that loads a child swf using SWFLoader class. the child swf is connecting to adobe flash media server using NetConnection class. using the parent swf i want to to display status regarding the connection. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an example on how to do so at `Tour de Flex` on the swfloader class related example.
so seeing the example plus reading the following URL resolved the issue.

Creating and Dispatching Custom Events in AS3

http://www.flashcoder.net/blog/?p=100

it didn't work for me at first but then i noticed a very similar question at:
[How to raise an event from a SWF in a SWFLoader to a parent Flex application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195150/how-to-raise-an-event-from-a-swf-in-a-swfloader-to-a-parent-flex-application)

and i noticed that the bubbles variable defaulted to false when it was supposed to be true.
that solved my problem.